# Hamiltonian of two-level spin system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, hamiltonian, spinors, two-level-system

Why is it the case that for a two-level system, say a particle which is a spin $1/2$ system (hence can either be spin up or spin down), in the absence of any external perturbation by a magnetic field or electric field, the Hamiltonian can be considered by $\hat{H} = \hbar \frac{\omega_0}{2}\hat{\sigma}_z$?

Also I don't really see how it is possible to have a Hamiltonian with no external influence to account for it?

Comment: Your instincts are good (specifically, you should be suspicious of such a Hamiltonian with no external influences).  But what makes you think this is the correct Hamiltonian for your system?  Are you sure you can assume no external field?

Comment: @Mike I'm not sure, but I was told by a Prof that this is the general Hamiltonian for a two level system in the absence of any external radiation or influence. Hence I am trying to understand what the source of this Hamiltonian is or if this whole assumption is incorrect, quite confusing.

Answer (score 3):

The *effect* of themagnetic field on the system - irrespective of how it is generated - is to split the energy level, i.e. raise the spin-up state and lower the spin-down state.  The Hamiltonian you have does exactly this.  The stength of the field is "hidden" in the parameter $\omega_0$, and is written this way so the units conveniently simplify: $\hbar \omega_0$ has units of energy and $\sigma_z$ is dimensionless.

Comment: Okay thanks but how do we know there will always be a magnetic field? I am assuming no electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: What field though? I am assuming no field at all. Are you saying that there is always a magnetic field for any two level spin system?

Comment: No I'm saying the above Hamiltonian models the effect of a *static* magnetic field on a spin-1/2 system.  The strength of $B$ is related to $\omega_0$ by the Larmor relation: $\omega_0=e B/m$ (depending on the units) see  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/larmor.html.  Radiation produces a time-dependent field, so you Hamiltonian does not include radiation as per your assumption.

Comment: Understood, I am familiar with this. I am asking something a bit different. I am asking if this Hamiltonian, which I mentioned, is appropriate for a two level spin system where there is no magnetic or electric fields present, no static and no radiation. You just have a two level spin sytem with no external static or radiation fields present. In other words, if we use this Hamiltonian, is there an assumption that there is some external field present (static or otherwise)?

Comment: magnetic and static; something that splits the enegy levels of the spins, and magnetic static is the easiest.  Anything else is equivalent to this *in a 2-level system*.

Comment: Okay but is the the answer to my last question yes or no?

Comment: Let me take a step back.  Your Hamiltonian can model *any* 2-level system, field or not, spin 1/2 or not. The energy difference between the levels is simply $\hbar\omega_0$.  The *prototype* of this kind of 2-level system system is a spin 1/2 particle in a static magnetic field.

Comment: Okay understood. This might be a stupid question. But if we consider just a spin $1/2$ particle in a vacuum, with no external influence, would this Hamiltonian still apply?

Comment: In vacuum there would be no energy difference between the spin up and spin down states..  The Hamiltonian $\sim \sigma_z$ always has an energy difference, so it would be appropriate to describe a system with no energy difference between the two states..

Answer (score 0):

The section on modelling 2 level hamiltonians with "fictitious spin" and "fictitious B field" might be useful here

[https://www.chem.uci.edu/~unicorn/249/Handouts/CTspinhalf.pdf](https://www.chem.uci.edu/%7Eunicorn/249/Handouts/CTspinhalf.pdf)

Comment: Links tend to rot over time, so link-only answers aren’t considered useful. Perhaps you could summarize the important info?